# Android. How do I dynamically change the color of the entire FrameLayout instead of just the color of the View backround?

Tags: android, view, background, android-framelayout

This is my main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    >

<ImageButton android:background="@null"  android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:src="@drawable/sample" android:id="@+id/pressThisButton" android:layout_y="40px" android:layout_x="20px"></ImageButton>
</FrameLayout>
```

In the Framelayout, I have a View v which contains the button pressThisButton.

When the button is pressed I am able to change the color of the padding background surrounding the button in the view--but not the background of the entire screen--using

```
private OnClickListener buttonClickListener = new OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick( View v )


        {


            v.setBackgroundColor(0xffff0000);
```

Is there a way in a FrameLayout to change both the view background and the entire screen color?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the `FrameLayout` using `findViewById` and set the background color on it.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. After I assigned an id to my frame layout, your suggestion worked perfectly.Thank you again for your help.